# Консольная программа с несколькими окнами/субокнами

Tags: perl

Возможно вопрос немного непонятен, но я сейчас подробно опишу, что необходимо:

Какие модули (или что-то иное) необходимы для консольной программы с несколькими окнами? Т.е. после запуска программы, должна иметься возможность переключаться с одного окна на другое.

Comment: (n)curses, не?....

Comment: http://pragmaticperl.com/issues/08/pragmaticperl-08-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-curses.html

Answer (score 0):

[Curses](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses)

[Curses::UI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses::UI)

[Curses::Toolkit](https://github.com/dams/curses-toolkit)

[Tickit - Terminal Interface Construction KIT](https://metacpan.org/release/Tickit)